# git: how to point/reset one branch to another in safe way

Tags: git

We have a master branch, where development PRs are pulled to, and a branch per environment which, when committed, will auto build that env.

So we have the following branches:

- master
- dev-env
- test-env
- hotfix-env
- stage-env
- prod-env

I want to do some experimentation on hotfix-env.

To do this I need to:

1. make hotfix-env the same as master.  I don't mind losing all history.
2. checkout hotfix-env
3. make a change branch
4. do some code changes.
5. commit the branch to origin
6. do a pull request of changes with hotfix-env
7. merget PR with hotfix-env
8. repeat from 3 till 7 until experiment finished.
9. copy required code changes to a temp location.
10. undoo hotfix-env by pointing it back to master.
11. make changes to master via feature branch etc.

The crux is I dont know how to do 1) and 10), and dont want to risk destroying master.

Is it something like:

1. git checkout master
2. git branch -f hotfix-env
3. git add *
4. git commit
5. git push origin hotfix-env

Or maybe its something like:

1. git checkout hotfix-env
2. git reset --hard master
3. git commit
4. git push origin hotfix-env

Answer (score 1):

> The crux is I dont know how to do ... make hotfix-env the same as master

```
git switch hotfix-env
git reset --hard master
```

There's your crux.